# Rblpapi: Dates ignored in Overrides in Bloomberg Data Series (bds) call

Tags: bloomberg

It seems the `bds()` call is not using the **overrides** correctly (or at all). This is the same question as has been already asked [Rblpapi R Bloomberg data download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024538/rblpapi-r-bloomberg-data-download) but I'm not sure how to comment on it with no reputation currently.

Example - trying to pull constituent bonds for yield curve (NZ Sovereign) construction.
There should be some differences between Dec 17th 2018 and Dec 17th 2019

```
require(Rblpapi)
bbg = blpConnect()

overrd = c("START_DT"="20181217", "END_DT"="20181217")
constituents2018 = bds("YCGT0049 Index", "Curve members",overrides = overrd)[,1]
overrd = c("START_DT"="20191217", "END_DT"="20191217")
constituents2019 = bds("YCGT0049 Index", "Curve members",overrides = overrd)[,1]

setdiff(constituents2018,constituents2019) #this should not be empty
```

Comment: Have you tried in Excel to see if the results are the same?

Comment: Yes assylias, the excel interface works as it should. The curve constituents change depending on time.